# How to change backgroundcolor of GroupDisplayBinding in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am trying to change the background color of GroupDisplayBinding only that is inside the list view without affecting the list. As you can see in the image, the background is lightgray, also I want to change the margin of it too if that's possible.

[image]

```
<ListView
                IsVisible="{Binding ShowList}"
                IsGroupingEnabled="True"
                HasUnevenRows="True"
                SelectionMode="None"
                SeparatorVisibility="None"
                BackgroundColor="#ffffff"
                GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding GroupName}"
                GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding ShortName}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding List}">
                <ListView.Behaviors>
                    <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding ListItemTappedCommand}"
                                                      EventName="ItemTapped" />
                </ListView.Behaviors>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Frame HasShadow="False"
                                   CornerRadius="0"
                                   Margin="2"
                                   Padding="10"
                                   BackgroundColor="#ffffff"
                                   BorderColor="#000000">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                             Spacing="0"
                                             Padding="0"
                                             Margin="0">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                           HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                           Style="{StaticResource ListTextStyle}"
                                           TextColor="#2278B5"/>
                                    <Label Text=">"
                                           Style="{StaticResource ListTextStyle}"
                                           TextColor="#2278B5"
                                           HorizontalOptions="End"
                                           FontSize="24" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

Comment: use a custom GroupHeaderTemplate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could take it one step further and implement our own custom header cell with a nice background color.

The demo is very simple and just contains a Label, which binds to `GroupName` and I am placing it inside of a StackLayout with a bit of custom padding and a background color.

```
 <ListView IsVisible="{Binding ShowList}"
            IsGroupingEnabled="True"
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            SelectionMode="None"
            SeparatorVisibility="None"
            BackgroundColor="#ffffff"
            GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding GroupName}"
            GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding ShortName}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding List}">

         // set the appearance of Header here as you want 
        <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell Height="25">
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="5"  BackgroundColor="#3498DB">
                        <Label Text="{Binding GroupName}"  TextColor="White" Margin="10" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            //...
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```